# Getting foreach to skip over iterations

Tags: php

I basically need something inside a foreach loop that will skip over the first 10 iterations of the array.

```
foreach($aSubs as $aSub){
   if($iStart > '0')
   //Skip first $iStart iterations.  Start at the next one
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Start a counter and use `continue` to skip the first ten loops:

```
$counter = 0 ;
foreach($aSubs as $aSub) {
    if($counter++ < 10) continue ;
    // Loop code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using iterators:

```
$a = array('a','b','c','d');
$skip = 2;
foreach (new LimitIterator(new ArrayIterator($a), $skip) as $e)
{
  echo "$e\n";
}
```

Output:

```
c
d
```

Or using the index (if the array has integer keys from 0 .. n-1):

```
foreach ($a as $i => $e)
{
  if ($i < $skip) continue;
  echo "$e\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If **$aSubs** is a not a object of an class that implements **Iterator**, and the indexes are sequential integers (starting at zero), it would easier to:

```
$count = count($aSubs);
for($i = 9, $i < $count; $i++) {
    // todo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to declare another variable `$counter` by using the advantage of `foreach` loop like this:

```
foreach ($aSubs as $index => $aSub) {
    if ($index < 10) continue;
    // Do your code here
}
```

This is a way better than declaring another variable outside the foreach loop.